# How to save Eclipse settings (fonts, formatting, etc.)?

Tags: eclipse

How can I export my settings (fonts, syntax coloring, formatting, etc.) in Eclipse 3.6, so I can use them again in another installation?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can save the folder '.metadata' in your workspace.

This folder contain your preferences, simply restore it after a re-installation and your done.

**Be aware that '.metadata' folder contains not only cosmetic or formatting preferences, but also projects,plugins,... settings that you may want to delete by creating a brand new workspace**

Prefer to copy the 'core' eclipse settings in:

'`.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/`'

Theses 'core' settings can be exported using 'File -> Export -> Preferences' too as Csaba_H said.
But the syntax coloring preferences for a specific language won't be exported.

Comment: Are font preferences exported in this method?

Answer (score 31):

Settings can be exported to a file using File -> Export -> Preferences, and you can import it to another Eclipse workspace.

Comment: Unfortunately, this export does not contain all settings in my case (Eclipse 4.2.2). E.g. SVN repositories and Checkstyle configuration is missing, even though I select to export all settings.

Comment: Same here. Various "Favorites" autocomplete preferences and plugin configurations are not included in this export.

Comment: Doesn't seem to export the font settings.