# How do I save the run and debug configurations in the eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

How do I save the run and debug configurations in the eclipse IDE?
Basically a lot of what I do in my job requires me to configure applications that I run often, but I forget these configurations, and it would be nice to have a backup of them if I have to reinstall eclipse. Any help appreciated.

This is the version I have:

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149

Comment: Isnt this the same question which was already answered? just take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214526/how-to-save-eclipse-settings-fonts-formatting-etc

Comment: No, launch configs are stored separately from workspace preferences.

Comment: I mean they can and should be saved independently from the workspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Run the app once
- Go to Run -> Run Configurations
- Select the existing launch config for the app
- Hit the Common tab
- Configure Save As -> Shared file

If you store them somewhere outside the workspace (e.g. on a shared drive) you may later import them into a different workspace: File -> Import -> Run/Debug -> Launch Configurations.

You may also select a config as a favorite if you like:

- Click the green Run icon in the toolbar
- Select Organize Favorites
- Add the desired launch configs

Comment: But that would mean I would have to do that to all run configurations, Isn't there a way to save all these configurations in one file that I can simply copy and replace

Comment: Hmm.. I see that they get saved as .launch files.. but how do I restore from them?

Comment: Restore? I case you mean "import" I added those instructions, too.